# How to build an array of dictionaries in python using generators( which are consumed by StreamingHttpResponse)

Tags: json, django, streaming, generator

I am trying to stream a large json response with django's StreamingHttpResponse.

```
class Annotations(APIView):
    """
    """
    def content_generator(self,request):
        imageObjs = Image.objects.all().values("id","name","path")
        for imageObj in imageObjs.iterator():
            imageData = {
                "name":imageObj["name"],
                "path":imageObj["path"]
            }
            yield json.dumps(imageData)


    def get(self,request):
        try:
            response = StreamingHttpResponse(self.content_generator(request), content_type = 'application/json')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="annotations.json"'
            return response
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception("Error in getting annotations")
            return Response({'detail':str(e)},status = status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

The problem with the above code is that the response is of the form :

```
{"name":"a","path":"xyz"}{"name":"b","path":"abc}......
```

which is an invalid JSON.
What i want to generate is:

```
[{"name":"a","path":"xyz"},{"name":"b","path":"abc}, ...]
```

(*notice the array brackets and comma separators)

Is there a way this could be achieved while using generators.?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Though its not clean.

```
def content_generator(self,request):
        startTime = time.time()
        imageObjs = Image.objects.values("id","name","path")
        currentImage = 0
        totalImages = imageObjs.count()-1 # insert command only until penultimate value
        yield "["
        for imageObj in imageObjs.iterator():
            imageData = {
                "name":imageObj["name"],
                "path":imageObj["path"]
            }
            yield json.dumps(imageData)
            if currentImage < totalImages:
                yield ","
            currentImage += 1
        yield "]"
```

Yield the brackets and comma from inside the generator itself.